# Does "HERE Maps API for JavaScript" fully supports GeoJSON format?

Tags: geojson, here-api

Does API supports holes in GeoJSON?
I have GeoJSON which is rendered with holes on geojson.io but when I render the same data within H.data.geojson.Reader it is rendered without holes.
I haven't found any information about additional options or so in API Reference and no questions related to this problem here on StackOverflow.
Shall I provide my code and data or someone knows whether holes are supported or not?

Comment: We are checking this alternatively you can try HERE XYZ https://developer.here.com/products/xyz and check if that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Does API documentation for XYZ Maps JS exists? Especially I'm interested in input parameters of HERE.cp.map.providers.GeoJSONProvider? Does it possible to pass GeoJSON object dynamically from the application instead of read data from URL?

Comment: Check this https://developer.here.com/documentation/xyz/map_customization_suite_ui_hlp/user_guide/index.html for XYZ Map Js.

Comment: Yes, I saw this documentation but this is User Guide and not API Reference. I can't find description of parameters there.

Comment: Current version of API doesn't support holes in GeoJSON, but the upcoming version (planned for next week) will support holes.

Comment: Great! Looking forward to new version.

Comment: As I understand new version has been released, since holes are visible now.

Comment: @vich, yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

Check the [example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/geoshapes/polygon-with-holes-on-the-map) which shows the holes with polygon, also to convert the result geometry into geoJSON object.

```
oGeoJSON ()Object
To obtain a GeoJSON representation of the given geometry.

See:
GeoJSON spec

Returns:
Type     Description
Object   A GeoJSON Geometry object representing the given geometry.
```